# class that wraps my entity object is not saving

Tags: c#, .net, entity

I may be going about this incorrectly but this is my class that I wrap my entity object:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace SSS.ServicesConfig.data
{
  public partial class GlobalSetting
  {
    private static GlobalSetting _globalSettings;

    public static GlobalSetting GlobalSettings
    {
      get
      {
        if (_globalSettings == null)
        {
          GetGlobalSetting();
        }
        return _globalSettings;
      }
    }

    private static void GetGlobalSetting()
    {
      try
      {      
        using (var subEntities = PpsEntities.DefaultConnection())
        {
          _globalSettings = (from x in subEntities.GlobalSettings
                            select x).FirstOrDefault();

          if (_globalSettings == null)
          {
            _globalSettings = new GlobalSetting();
            _globalSettings.GlobalSettingId = Guid.NewGuid();
            _globalSettings.CompanyCode = string.Empty;
            _globalSettings.CorporationId = Guid.Empty;
            _globalSettings.DefaultBranch = "01";
            _globalSettings.SourceId = Guid.Empty;
            _globalSettings.TokenId = Guid.Empty;
            subEntities.AddToGlobalSettings(_globalSettings);
            subEntities.SaveChanges();
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Logging.Log("An error occurred.", "GetGlobalSetting", Apps.ServicesConfig, ex);
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to retrieve data: [{0}].", ex.Message));
      }
    }

    internal static void SaveGlobalSettings()
    {
      using (var entities = PpsEntities.DefaultConnection())
      {
        entities.Attach(_globalSettings);
        entities.SaveChanges();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make it where they have to go through my class to get the settings record and save it though the same class. This is in a separate project that several other projects are going to import.

My save isn't saving to the database and I see no errors or changes on the record. In this particular table, there is only one record so it's not adding another record either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: when you catch the error like this way then you will never find the root problem. you need the innenexception.

Comment: I debugged it and it's not throwing an error. It's going right through the `SaveGlobalSettings()` without an problems.

Answer (score 0):

First your save is not being called after the initial value is assigned to _globalSettings.

Second You should not be trying to change the value with a get accessor.  It is bad form.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx

I recommend that you separate the responsibility of the save to the database to a new method (you could expose the SaveGlobalSettings method by making it public), but if you are determined to obfuscate the save from the user, then I would recommend you remove the save to the database from get accessor of the GlobalSettings property, create a set accessor for the GlobalSettings property, and put the save to the database in the GlobalSettings properties set accessor.

One other note, you are killing your stack trace.

```
throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to retrieve data: [{0}].", ex.Message));
```

You can still catch and log the exception the way that your are doing it, but re-throw the exception like this:

```
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logging.Log("An error occurred.", "GetGlobalSetting", Apps.ServicesConfig, ex);
    throw;
  }
```

This will preserve the original exception.

Comment: Your first thought is only partially true. If I do a `SaveGlobalSettings()` before I do a get, it will be empty. That is not what is happening in this case.

Comment: Second thought noted. Recommendation, the save you are seeing is only creating a blank record, saving it, and then returning it, if no record is found. The save isn't in the get except when it returns a blank record.